# Create multiple case statements in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to understand how work the expression in SAP HANA.

I want to create multiple case in one expression.

I have this:

```
case when (case when "name" = 'NomEntreprise'
then "value"
end) = 'Entreprise Test'
Then 'OK'
end
```

But when I'm doing this, it doesn't accept the syntax of the code, someone can explain me why ?

```
case when (case when "name" = 'NomEntreprise'
then "value"
end) = 'Entreprise FAIL'
Then 'FAIL'
end
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Please indicate the exact error message and please provide a minimal example which compiles (yours is just a part of a SELECT or whatever).

Comment: Possibly the syntax error is `SQL-ERROR 260 invalid column name: value: line # col # (at pos #)` if you indicate `"value"` for being a text literal, but in that case you should use double quotes. But if `value` is a column name, then the syntax error is something else. Please clarify.

Comment: I understand, that the first statements succeeds and the second fails? There is no reason for this behaviour given the two statements as only two strings changed. So probably your question is missing context, that explains your observation.